# pack://application:,,,/ResourceFile.xaml Never Works

Tags: .net, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have never been able to get this format of reference a Resource Dictionary to work. What am I missing.

Scenario:

Creating and assembly with some usercontrols in it.
At root have said file **{root}/Themes/ColorThemes.xaml** 
The ColorThemes.xaml file has its build action set to [Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Then in in xaml file further down let say **{root}/Controls/ButtonStyles/Themes/ButtonThemes.xaml** (note the path is just an example)
in this file I have the following bit of code:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Themes/ColorThemes.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

As far as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states this should work (as I understand it), and while I am in the designer it seems to be fine (all the colors load etc) however when I then go and compile my application and run it I get this error {"Cannot locate resource 'themes/colorthemes.xaml'."} which is strange because it seemed to be using just fine in the builder. So I am quiet confused because it seems to not coincide with the documentation.
 So if someone can explain to me what I am missing :)

Note: if I change the previous code to

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../../../Themes/ColorThemes.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

It works fine, however for cleanese pack://application: .

Comment: pack://application:,,,/YOURASSEMBLYNAME;component/Themes/ColorThemes.xaml to be sure. Uri MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx . It's also common to merge dictionaries or alle cc xaml in Themes/Generic.xaml. I usually split my cc's and call them CcName.Generic.xaml. But that's just my taste..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try:

```
pack://application:,,,/YOURNAMESPACEHERE/ColorThemes.xaml
```

E.g.

```
pack://application:,,,/Themes/ColorThemes.xaml
```

Comment: Isn't that the very exactly code which posted Heinrich in his question? Probably I didn't safetyOtter's point since this answer seemed helpful for quite a lot of people. But maybe could add further explanation :-).

Answer (score 10):

Can't reproduce your problem. All these variations work fine:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Themes/ColorThemes.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/ColorThemes.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Themes/ColorThemes.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Note that `pack://application:,,,` is optional and `/` refers to the root of the current assembly.

Please provide complete minimal example which reproduces your problem.

Comment: It was caused by the namespace habits of the project. It appears the problem is caused by differing namespaces in the same assembly.

Comment: I ran into the same thing which is why it was the first thing I thought of.