# WPF Button Images Show at Design Time but Not Run Time

Tags: .net, wpf, image, xaml

I have two images stored in a resources folder that are have Build Action set to Resources and Copy to Output Directory set to Do not copy.  The images are "font.png" and "open.png".  When I view the designer, the images appear in the buttons exactly as I would like them too, however; when I run the application the buttons are empty.  Below is my XAML, what am I doing wrong?

```
<Window x:Class="Preferences"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:se="clr-namespace:TheRandomizerWPF.MarkupExtensions"
        xmlns:res ="clr-namespace:TheRandomizerWPF.My"
        xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="Preferences" 
        Icon="The Randomizer.ico"
        Height="227.509" 
        Width="453.736"
        WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=WindowStyle}" >
    <Window.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="Font" Source="pack://application,,,Resources/Resources/font.png" />
        <Image x:Key="Open" Source="Pack://application,,,Resources/Resources/open.png" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DockPanel Margin="3" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ContentPanel}">
            <CheckBox Name="chkAutoUpdate" Content="Auto Update" Margin="6,3,3,3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Margin="3" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ContentPanel}">
            <Label Name="lblResultFont" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="160" Margin="3" Content="Default Result Font" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />            
            <Button Name="btnResultFont" Margin="3" Height="22" Width="22" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Font}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtResultFont" Margin="3" Height="21" IsReadOnly="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Margin="3,3,3,0" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ContentPanel}">
            <Label Name="lblTempDirectory" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="160" Margin="3" Content="Temporary Directory" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <Button Name="btnTempDirectory" Margin="3" Width="22" Height="22" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Open}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtTempDirectory" Margin="3" Height="22" IsReadOnly="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Margin="3,0,3,0" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ContentPanel}">
            <Label Name="lblCustomGrammarDirectory" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="160" Margin="3" Content="Custom Grammar Directory" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <Button Name="btnCustomGrammarDirectory" Margin="3" Width="22" Height="22" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Open}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtCustomGrammarDirectory" Margin="3" Height="21" IsReadOnly="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Margin="3,0,3,3" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ContentPanel}">
            <Label Name="lblThemeDirectory" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Width="160" Margin="3" Content="Theme Directory" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
            <Button Name="btnThemeDirectory" Margin="3" Width="22" Height="22" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Open}" />
            <TextBox Name="txtThemeDirectory" Margin="3" Height="21" IsReadOnly="True" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Margin="3" LastChildFill="False">
            <Button Name="btnOk" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ActionButton}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="80" Margin="3" Content="_Ok" IsDefault="True" />
            <Button Name="btnCancel" Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ActionButton}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="80" Margin="3" Content="_Cancel" IsCancel="True" />
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: take a look at these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289367/pack-application-resourcefile-xaml-never-works  it might be that the pack URI is not correct (there are multiple formats that work, and im not familiar with what you have as being a valid one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your image source URi has an incorrect format. It should be something like

```
pack://application:,,,/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml
```

(note the colon after "application")

What I usually do is just having

```
Source="Subfolder/ResourceFile.png"
```

which is simpler, more readable, and works ;-)

Comment: This was my issue.  The path that worked was:
`pack://application:,,,/Resources/Open.png`

Answer (score 0):

I think you URI is incorrect you must put the source like the before answer
you URI work if the image was EmbededResources.